# How to modify text inside of a csv file from command prompt

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I have a set of data from my Student Information System and I want to change the username in the [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) from `test.student` to an email address `test_student@testdomain.com` that is in column `D` of the `.csv` file.

Essentially it will append `@testdomain.com` to whats currently in column `D`.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
Studentnumber,lastname,firstname,useraccount,gradyear,coursenumber,gradesem1,gradesem2,gradefinal
17553,test,student,test_student,2016,1811,A,_,_
```

I got this from a sample to play with and it doesn't seem to be modifying `col4` like i was trying to get it to.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inputCSV=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\studentgrades.csv
set outputCSV=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\outputtest.csv

(for /f "tokens=1-9* delims=," %%a IN (%inputCSV%) DO (
  set "col4=%%d"
  set "col4=!col4:foo=bar!"
  set "col4=!col4:test=abc!"
  echo %%a,%%b,%%c,!col4!,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i
))>%outputCSV%
```

Expected result would change from:

```
17553,test,student,test_student,2016,1811,A,_,_
```

to this:

```
17553,test,student,test_student@testdomain.com,2016,1811,A,_,_
```

Comment: The code you posted has no relation to your stated goals - of course it doesn't give your "expected" result. It looks like you grabbed some code that someone else wrote, made no effort to understand what it does, and are simply asking others to do your work.

Comment: Powershell rather than cmd.exe is the way to go for csv parsing. Are you open to that?

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake made is choosing `cmd.exe` as script interpreter for modification of a text file. Windows command processor is designed for executing commands and applications, but not for modifying text files. All other script interpreters installed on Windows by default like [Windows Script Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) with `cscript.exe` (console version) and `wscript.exe` (Windows GUI version) for **VBScript** and **JScript** scripts or `powershell.exe` for **PowerShell** scripts have built-in features to modify text in files.

However, for some unknown reason the task should be done with a batch file interpreted with `cmd.exe` and so here is a batch file solution. This task could be done with using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using **JScript**. So it is not really a pure Windows command processor solution because of JScript and `cscript.exe` is used to make the real job.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "InputCSV=%UserProfile%\Desktop\studentgrades.csv"
set "OutputCSV=%UserProfile%\Desktop\outputtest.csv"

if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" (
    echo Error: Missing file jrepl.bat in "%~dp0".
    goto EndBatch
)
if not exist "%InputCSV%" (
    echo Error: Missing input file "%InputCSV%".
    goto EndBatch
)

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^((?:[^,]*,){3}[^,]*)" "$1@testdomain.com" /F "%InputCSV%" /O "%OutputCSV%"

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

The batch file **JREPL.BAT** must be stored in same directory as the batch file with the code above. For that reason the batch file checks first if **JREPL.BAT** really exists in directory of the batch file and exits if this condition is not true with printing before an error message.

Then the batch file checks if the input file exists at all and outputs an error message if this is not the case.

Last **JREPL.BAT** is called with regular expression search and replace string to make the replace with writing the modified content into specified output file.

The meaning of the search expression is:

- `^` ... start each search from beginning of a line.
- `(`...`)` ... is a capturing group. Everything found with the expression inside the loop is backreferenced with `$1` in replace string to keep it unmodified.
- `(?:`...`)` ... is a non-capturing group used here to apply an expression multiple times.
- `[^,]` ... is a negative character class definition to find any character **NOT** being a comma.
- `*` ... is a multiplier applied on the negative character class definition to find 0 or more characters not being a comma.
- `,` ... a literal comma must be found next after **0** or more characters not being a comma.
- `{3}` ... the expression inside non-marking group must be applied exactly three times for a positive match.
- `[^,]*` .. once more any character except comma **0** or more times must be found for a positive match.

So this search and replace inserts left to fourth comma the string `@testdomain.com` and does not change anything else in CSV file.

This simple search and replace solution works only under following conditions:

1. The fourth data value is not enclosed in `"` as otherwise `@testdomain.com` would be inserted wrong between `"` at end of string value and the comma being interpreted as separator between the field values.
2. Non of the first four field values contain a comma as literal character in a double quoted value string as otherwise `@testdomain.com` would be inserted at wrong position in data row.
3. Non of the first four field values contain one or more newline characters in a double quoted value string because of the CSV file is interpreted by the search and replace line by line and not data row by data row.

All three conditions are definitely possible in a CSV file according to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) better explained by Wikipedia article about [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_separated_value). A real scripting or programming solution with full CSV support would be necessary in case of one of these three conditions cannot be kept by content of CSV file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 being the batch file itself.
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`